# R how to create a dictionary of unique values

Tags: r, dictionary

I have a column in a dataframe that contains multiple values like this

```
           fruits
  1   apple,banana
  2 banana,peaches
  3        peaches
  4          mango
```

Is there a way to create a dictionary of unique values for fruits which 
is will create a new column fruits with values :

```
 fruits = apple,banana,peaches,mango
```

UPDATE: I need the value as a column and not a list of just unique values . So that I can create a final dataframe that would have the following :

```
          fruits      fruit_apple  fruit_banana  fruit_mango  fruit_peacheas 
 1   apple,banana          1            0             0             0
 2   banana,peaches        0            1             0             1
 3   peaches               0            0             0             1
 4   mango                 0            0             1             0
```

Comment: do you want each row of the new column to have all the unique values?

Comment: i want a dictionary of all unique values since i would need to make it a column that i would mark a 1 if the value exists on the original column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the new column to be that concatenated list repeated? Sorry, it's not particularly clear. Assuming that's the case though, and that your `data.frame` consists of strings not factors;

```r
df <- read.delim(
text="fruits
apple,banana
banana,peaches
peaches
mango", 
sep="\n", 
header=TRUE,
stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df
#>           fruits
#> 1   apple,banana
#> 2 banana,peaches
#> 3        peaches
#> 4          mango

df$uniquefruits <- paste0(unique(unlist(strsplit(df$fruits, split=","))), collapse=",")
df
#>           fruits               uniquefruits
#> 1   apple,banana apple,banana,peaches,mango
#> 2 banana,peaches apple,banana,peaches,mango
#> 3        peaches apple,banana,peaches,mango
#> 4          mango apple,banana,peaches,mango
```

Or do you mean taking only the values from your first `fruits` column that are not duplicated elsewhere?

**Update:** Based on comments, I think this is what you're after:

```r
uniquefruits <- unique(unlist(strsplit(df$fruits, split=",")))
uniquefruits
#> [1] "apple"   "banana"  "peaches" "mango"

df2 <- cbind(df, 
             sapply(uniquefruits, 
                    function(y) apply(df, 1, 
                                      function(x) as.integer(y %in% unlist(strsplit(x, split=","))))))
df2
#>           fruits apple banana peaches mango
#> 1   apple,banana     1      1       0     0
#> 2 banana,peaches     0      1       1     0
#> 3        peaches     0      0       1     0
#> 4          mango     0      0       0     1
```

In theory, you could do this with `dplyr` but I can't figure out how to automate the column processing for the `rowwise` `mutate` (anyone know how?)

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(apple    = as.integer("apple"   %in% unlist(strsplit(fruits, ","))),
                            banana   = as.integer("banana"  %in% unlist(strsplit(fruits, ","))),
                            peaches  = as.integer("peaches" %in% unlist(strsplit(fruits, ","))),
                            mango    = as.integer("mango"   %in% unlist(strsplit(fruits, ","))))
#> Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>           fruits apple banana  peaches mango
#>            <chr> <int>  <int>    <int> <int>
#> 1   apple,banana     1      1        0     0
#> 2 banana,peaches     0      1        1     0
#> 3        peaches     0      0        1     0
#> 4          mango     0      0        0     1
```

Comment: the uniquefruits is what I need but i would like it to be 5 individual columns since I would use it as a binary indicator later on

Comment: So you want a column for each unique fruit, with a 1/0 for whether or not there's a match between that column and `fruits`? Is the full list of possible fruits fixed?

Comment: the full list of possible fruits would be fixed since it would be all unique values in the original column fruits for all the data. Then I need to apply a function to go back to the data and mark it 1/0    - i updated the final output above

Comment: Updated with what I suspect you're after.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll  another option for you is `library(qdapTools); mtabulate(strsplit(df1$fruits, ","))`

Comment: @akrun what package does library(qdapTools) exist since when I tried to add that library it error does not exist

Comment: @EB  There is a [CRAN package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdapTools/index.html).  Which version of R do you have?

Comment: @akrun version.string R version 3.2.2

Answer (score 2):

We can do this easily with `cSplit_e` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(df1, "fruits", ",", type = "character", fill = 0)
#          fruits fruits_apple fruits_banana fruits_mango fruits_peaches
#1   apple,banana            1             1            0              0
#2 banana,peaches            0             1            0              1
#3        peaches            0             0            0              1
#4          mango            0             0            1              0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(fruits = c("apple,banana", "banana,peaches", "peaches", 
"mango")), .Names = "fruits", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: Neat! Hadn't seen that package before. Slightly aside - do you know how to automate the `mutate` over columns from my answer? My searching only dug up a Quora question (from a similar username to yours) asking the same.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll  You can try `library(dplyr);library(tidyr);df1 %>% mutate(n = row_number()) %>% separate_rows(fruits)  %>% mutate(n1 = 1) %>% spread(fruits, n1, fill = 0) %>% bind_cols(df1,.) %>% select(-n)`

Answer (score 0):

with base R:

```
fruits <- sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$fruits), split=','))))
cols <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(0, nrow(df)*length(fruits)), ncol=length(fruits)))
names(cols) <- fruits
df <- cbind.data.frame(df, cols)
df <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x){fruits <- strsplit(x['fruits'], split=','); x[unlist(fruits)] <- 1;x})))

df
          fruits apple banana mango peaches
1   apple,banana     1      1     0       0
2 banana,peaches     0      1     0       1
3        peaches     0      0     0       1
4          mango     0      0     1       0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below steps,

1) Just split dataframe by comma using strsplit function.

2) Unlist a split list of vectors into a single vector.

3) Then take unique of list.fruits character vector.

**Here is the solution,**

```
# DataFrame of fruits
f <- c("apple,banana","banana,peaches","peaches","mango")
fruits <- as.data.frame(f)
# fruits dataframe
               f
#1   apple,banana
#2 banana,peaches
#3        peaches
#4          mango
list.fruits <- unlist(strsplit(f,split=","))
unique.fruits <- unique(list.fruits)



# Result 
 unique.fruits
[1] "apple"   "banana"  "peaches" "mango"
```